# How to get the location from geotagged tweets with tweepy?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I have the following code that looks for only geotagged tweets in English:

```
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,
                           q="google",
                           geocode="40.7142700,-74.0059,5000km",
                           rpp=100,
                           result_type="recent",
                           include_entities=True,
                           lang="en").items():
    print (tweet.created_at,tweet.text)
```

Now how can I print along with the created date and the tweet the location of the tweet? I tried different things like tweet.geocode and tweet.locale but with no success. Please help me, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look at `tweet.place`. It's documented here: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/data-dictionary/overview/tweet-object

However, even though Twitter may return one or more tweets that correspond to the geocode that you provide, those tweets do not always contain a `place` object.

Comment: Thank you and that's true, I am not getting any tweets. Any idea how to get only the users that have disclosed their location?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with throwing away the tweets that don't have `place`. If you are looking for old tweets that is your only option. However, if you stream tweets filtered by location, then every tweet you receive will have a `place` field.

Answer (score 1):

written a code for geolocation where you can give country name. you can check my git link: https://github.com/Sy-Muzammil/Tweet-Crawlers/blob/master/geo_country.py
After executing the code you will get csv file where you will get (tweet_id tweet_time tweet_place tweet_text)